# How to SSRS DrillThrough with multiple rows & multiple parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, drillthrough

Hi currently i am doing a SSRS Report & i wanna make a drillthrough action

may i know how to make drillthrough depends on rows?

i had try like this & still not working

```
           =SWITCH(ROWNUMBER("ReportDetails")=1 ,"Jan"
           ROWNUMBER("ReportDetails")=2 ,"Feb")
```

my desired output

[image]

1 main table & 1 sub table

like if i clicked on the feb's amt then will drillthrough to the feb's details, if i click on jan's amt then will drillthrough to Jan's details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic process is as follows.

Create a new report that accepts 'Month' as a parameter.

The dataset should filter based on your parameter so it may look something like this...

```
SELECT * FROM myDetailTable WHERE Month = @Month
```

Test this is working by manully setting the parameter and once you are happy with it, go back to your main report.

In the main report, right-click the cell that you want the user to click on to drill into your new report. This could be any textbox in the row, for exmaple the 'Amt' column. When you right-click, choose "textbox properties" then click on the "Action".

In the Action dialog, select "Go to Report", select your new subreport (the one we created above) in the "Specify a report" drop-down.

In the paramaters list, add a new parameter,

In the "Name" column 'Month'

In the value column, select the name of the dataset column that contains your month, for example [Month]

That's pretty much all there is to it.

Comment: do i need to do an expression for my data as if when i click feb then the feb's details come out ?

Comment: i tried this  =SWITCH(ROWNUMBER("ReportDetails")=1 ,"Jan"
                   ROWNUMBER("ReportDetails")=2 ,"Feb")

Comment: No expressions required, the just follow the instructions above. When you click on the textbox where you set the 'Action' it knows which row you clicked so we just need to pass the correct colume (Month) to the subreport.

Comment: If this answer helped solve you issue, please mark it accepted rather than upvoting as this helps others when trying to find simliar answers.I see that you have asked 5 questiosn recently and none of the anserws have been marked as accepted. You will help the community and yourself if you follow the guidelines.